# Changing visibility doesn't work on C# windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to display a progessbar during some work but the visibility doesn't change...

```
private void GestureListener_PinchCompleted(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    DoWork();//quite long (4-5 seconds)
    progressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Is there a resfreh method or something like that? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing `DoWork()` in the UI thread, blocking it for 4 to 5 seconds. This is why you are unable to see the progress bar.

Consider to call DoWork in a separate thread:

```
private async void GestureListener_PinchCompleted(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    await Task.Run(()=> DoWork()); //quite long (4-5 seconds)
    progressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

[Asynchronous Programming For Windows Phone 8](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Asynchronous_Programming_For_Windows_Phone_8)